Could cosmic rays induce a vacuum decay in the future?
I've been told that very energetic cosmic rays could cause a vacuum phase transition or vacuum decay (and even could cause a true vacuum level to go "uphill" to a false vacuum) due to their high energy levels.
I've found some references supporting this claim 1, 2, 3, 4
But also one paper arguing that vacuum decay induced by particle collisions (such as cosmic rays collisions) would be suppressed and no amount of cosmic rays collisions occurring in nature (even in the largest production sites) could trigger such phenomenon 5. But at the same time, the author speculates that in the future with powerful colliders we could cause a vacuum decay. However, I don't really get how the author says that a futuristic civilization could get enough energy to cause a vacuum phase transition while saying that even the most energetic events in the universe producing high-energy cosmic rays (like quasars and AGN) would fail to do so. I mean, I'm pretty sure there will be more energy in such natural events than in a particle collider even if we are talking about futuristic potential scenarios.
Therefore, is it possible or not that cosmic rays collisions may trigger such a vacuum decay? And if not, or if it is unclear, could it be triggered by other mechanisms (like certain types of black holes for example)?

Isn't everything regarding vacuum decay speculative at best? Also, it seems you're basically asking us to read a 24 page document (at minimum) and regurgitate the information contained to provide you with an answer, which isn't really something we do here.

Though just by reading the abstract on the arxiv link, it looks like they're assuming that a futurist collider could focus the particle collisions and force the required threshold of Higgs quant required for the decay (and presumably the focusing isn't something that natural CR colliders can do).

If this were possible, then it would have been triggered a long time ago by other technical civilizations. Since it hasn't we can be sure that the authors of your source are wrong.

@FlatterMann perhaps the civilization that did this is outside our cosmological horizon :)

@vengaq That sets an extremely low limit on civilizations in the universe. I don't subscribe to such statements. They are, IMHO, a fallback to geocentrism and claims of special creation of the human race. Let's leave such nonsense for tribal politics.

@KyleKanos and would it be completely impossible that in natural sources the cosmic rays get sufficiently concentrated to trigger such a decay?

@FlatterMann the thing is that if we necessarily assume that advanced civilizations already exist (as you seem to say in your comment) it is far more likely that we are a simulation running in their computers, or that they have contacted with us already... So, perhaps we should not assume so quickly that there are billions of such civilizations and say that perhaps the vast majority of them in a given Hubble volume, as evolution takes a lot of time, they are mostly at best similar to us in technological progress

@vengaq I don't assume anything about stuff that has never been observed. That's not scientific. If you want to speculate that you are just a number in a computer because the universe is still here, that's your personal choice. I can't see how you get logically from one to the other, though.

@FlatterMann you said that you don't assume anything about things that have not been observed, yet you assumed that a vacuum decay triggered by cosmic rays must be false since if it were right an advanced civilization would have already done it (a process that hasn't been observed)

@vengaq The question was about the possibility of triggering a vacuum decay using an advanced accelerator. I simply don't assume that mankind is special with regards to that technology and if we are not special, then the fact that we are all still here is a pretty strong limit on either the possibility of such a technology OR the number of technological civilizations. Since I didn't assume that we are special (one of a kind) that also rules out the latter possibility. Leaves the more or less obvious statement that the universe is a pretty stable construct.

The usual line of reasoning about vacuum decay treats it as a random phenomenon: there are events where it might be triggered, and since it has not happened yet we get a bound on how likely it is. Normal physics papers do not assume civilizations as possible triggers, but it does not matter: a supercivilization is just a rare physical phenomenon too, not too different from a gamma ray burst except that we have not observed any so far. So you can bound the probability due to any kind of cause based on observing the current universe, getting a rate $\ll 10^{-9}$ per year (Tegmark & Bostrom 2005).
This is similar to many other arguments that came up about particle accelerator risks: if the LHC could trigger vacuum decay, strangelets, black holes or other bad things, we should expect to observe many such events due to cosmic rays. We don't, so we have a good reason to not to be worried. (Some complications and conditions apply, see (Ord, Hillerbrand & Sandberg 2008)).
One can argue that it takes a deliberate trigger to put nature into a state that is exceedingly improbable normally (after all, fusion triggered by fission chain reactions are very rare in nature but humans set them up). That is dealt with by the Tegmark & Bostrom argument for our past lightcone, but if you also think supercivilizations have a nonstationary emergence rate (not too crazy, perhaps) then past data does not give any assurances. Current physical theory on the other hand places few bounds on what clever minds wielding technologies we do not yet have can and cannot do, so it is hard to do a good assessment. But we have decent reasons to think natural causes have had a lot of gigalightyear hypervolumes to play out in, and so far they have not produced these effects due to black holes of all sizes, cosmic rays under extreme conditions, and other unusual conditions.

plus LHC's blackhole isn't going to be at rest in the lab frame...it's going to zing off into space on a tangent to Geneva, evaporation notwithstanding.

@JEB - That is one of the complications, since cosmic rays definitely do produce debris with above escape speed velocities due to momentum conservation, but it takes a fair bit of effort to show that LHC debris is likely to have it (after all, the system is supposed to have net zero momentum in the lab frame).

The thing is, would it be completely impossible that in natural sources the cosmic rays get sufficiently concentrated to trigger such a decay (as the paper from Strumia seems to suggest) @AndersSandberg

@vengaq - While the paper scenario looks extremely improbable, there is a lot of weird things in nature. While we can estimate plausibility of particular scenarios, it is usually good to also bound entire classes of scenarios we do not even know what they are, when estimating risk.
